# Pyspark Checkpointing in Dataproc(StackOverFlowError)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I faced stackoveroverflow error when persisting dataset with pyspark. I am casting whole dataframe into doubletype and then persisting to calculate statistics, and I read that checkpointing is a solution to stackoverflow. However, I am having trouble with implementing it in dataproc.

1. I am working with pyspark, and when I checkpoint the dataframe and checkedpointed with df.isCheckpointed(), it returns false. However, when I debug it, df.rdd.is_checkpointed says True. Is there any issue with the package / am I doing something wrong?
2. I thought localCheckpoint is more appropriate for my purpose(https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#localCheckpoint()), as my problem was simply DAG depth was too deep, but I couldn't find any use case. Also, if I just checkpointed RDD says it is checkpointed(as in first question), but if I tried localcheckpoint, it says it is not. Has anyone tried this function?
3. After I tried with local standalone mode, I tried it with dataproc. I tried both hdfs and google cloud storage, but either way the storage was empty, but rdd says it is checkpointed.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using localCheckpoint, it will write to the local disk of executors, not to HDFS/GCS: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#localCheckpoint--.

Also note that there's an eager (checkpoint immediately) and non-eager (checkpoint when the RDD is actually materialized) mode to checkpointing. That may affect what those methods return. The code is often the best documentation: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1615.

In general, please attach sample code (repros) to questions like this -- that way we can answer your question more directly.

Comment: For localcheckpoint, I have read that it writes to local disk as you said, so I didn't set up any directory for that. I am looking for ways where I can check I have checkpointed correctly as all the flags that I mentioned said false.

Comment: I am not familiar with the word "materialized" but after checkpointing, I am persisting rdd and collecting the statistics, and even after that I can't find rdds in the directory

Comment: Sorry that I can't share the whole codes, but at the moment where I checkpoint rdds, I simply wrote dataframe.rdd.checkpoint()/dataframe.persist() and before that, sparkcontext.setCheckpointDir("gs://......." ) for checkpointing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp dir using your `SparkSession` object:

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoints")


dataframe_name = # Any Spark Dataframe of type <pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame>
```

at this point of time, the `dataframe_name` would be a `DAG`, which you can store as a checkpoint like,

```
dataframe_checkpoint = dataframe_name.checkpoint()
```

`dataframe_checkpoint` is also a spark dataframe of type `<pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame>` but instead of the `DAG`, it stores the result of the query

**Use checkpoints if:**

1. the computation takes a long time
2. the computing chain is too long
3. depends too many RDDs